# android studio - zxing barcode scanner - custom layout

Tags: android, android-layout, barcode, zxing

I am opening the scanner like this

```
IntentIntegrator integrator = new IntentIntegrator(activity);
integrator.setDesiredBarcodeFormats(IntentIntegrator.ALL_CODE_TYPES);
integrator.setPrompt(message);
integrator.setCameraId(0);
integrator.setBeepEnabled(false);
integrator.setBarcodeImageEnabled(false);
integrator.initiateScan();
```

How can I change the layout?

I want to add a button to the scanner view and also increase the font of the prompt.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to use this library with a custom layout, you'll have to build the layout yourself. The `IntentIntegrator` just launch a default activity that is part of the library, there aren't much customization options there. You can have a look at the documentation [here](https://github.com/journeyapps/zxing-android-embedded/blob/master/EMBEDDING.md) in order to learn how to embed their component into your own layout.

Hope this helps!